# In void getData() , How can I access the memory location returmed by void* pointer?

Tags: c++

when I try to enter elements through getData() function, I get error segmentation fault(core dumped). 
I am not able to enter elements into array. I am not able to understand why i cannot access the memory location returned by void* into Class type.
size of *parr is 4 bytes, still I cannot data into that memory location???

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Array
{
int *arr;
public:
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    void *parr=::new int[size];
    //cout<<sizeof(parr);
    return parr;
}
void operator delete(void *parr)
{
    ::delete (int*)parr;
}
void getData()
{
    cout<<"Enter the elements";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
}
void showData()
{
    cout<<"Array is:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout<<arr[i];
}
```

};

```
int main()
{
Array *A=new Array;
A->getData();
//A->showData();
(*A).showData();
delete A;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you overloading `new` and `delete`?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: where are you allocating the memory to arr... you're just instantiating the class

Comment: Actually, I want to do it using operator overloading only

Comment: One side note: in C++, unlike C, there is almost no valid use case for `void*`. Use templates, inheritance, overloading instead. When you're attempting to use `void*`, double-recheck you design. And then fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably meant to do instead of overloading the `new` and `delete` operators for class `Array`, is to write appropriate constructor and destructor functions:

```
class Array {
    int *arr;
public:
    Array(size_t size) : arr(new int[size]) {
    }
    ~Array() {
        delete arr;
    }
    // ...
};
```